# Regex to allow numbers, plus symbol, minus symbol and brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex that allows only the following 0-9, plus symbol, minus symbol and brackets (). No limitations on length of each of the mentioned. So far I have this but it does not seem to work.

```
/^[0-9 -+]+$/
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sN6lT1/1

It works actually, I just added the parenthesis.

Comment: When you say "only allows" what is it you actually mean, it matches a part of a string or the whole string? Is there any order in which the characters must appear or how many of each are allowed? What are you actually trying to achieve with this regex?

Comment: Any part of the string should be allowed to have what is mentioned above, at the start in the middle or at the end.

Answer (score 25):

Hyphen `-` has to be at the end of charlist, else it means interval.

```
/^[0-9 ()+-]+$/
```

0-9 is possible to write shortly as `\d`

```
/^[\d ()+-]+$/
```

Answer (score 13):

This should work for you:

```
^[\d\(\)\-+]+$
```

`^` -> start of string

`\d` -> same as [0-9]

`+` -> one or more repetitions

`$` -> end of string

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wN1sM3/5)

```js
var re = /^[\d\(\)\-+]+$/m; 
var str = ['09+()1213+-','fa(-ds'];
var m;
var result = "";
 
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if ((m = re.exec(str[i])) !== null) {
        if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
            re.lastIndex++;
        }
        // View your result using the m-variable.
        // eg m[0] etc.
 
    }
  result += "\""+str[i]+  "\"" + " is matched:" + (m != null) + "</br>";
}

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = result
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To match digits, +, -, (, and ) use:

```
[+()\d-]+
```

The trick is the position of the characters inside the character class.

---

```
if (/^[+()\d-]+$/.test(text)) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var re = /^[\w\(\)\-\!\+\*\&\%\$#\@\[\]\{\}\<\>\s]+$/m; 
var str = ['09+()1213+-[#test@gmail{}<>','fa(-ds'];
var m;
var result = "";
 
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if ((m = re.exec(str[i])) !== null) {
        if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
            re.lastIndex++;
        }
        // View your result using the m-variable.
        // eg m[0] etc.
 
    }
  result += "\""+str[i]+  "\"" + " is matched:" + (m != null) + "</br>";
}

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = result
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[\d\(\)\+\-\(\)]
```

That should do it.

EDIT: But since some agree the escaping is too much, here ya go:

```
[\d+()-]
```

[image]

Comment: Why escape so heavily? And where are the anchors and the quantifier?

Comment: Because it can match every character. This will capture it all.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this... lol. It's a working answer. Surely it can be done without the escaping, but why downvote a working answer? Makes no sense why it should be downvoted.

Comment: I didn't. It may be a working answer under some conditions, yes.

Comment: "under some conditions"? http://i.imgur.com/66E3v2T.png - Works fine in Javascript, that's for sure.